# How to make a special type using template string from object?

Tags: typescript

I have this object describing Legend for Chart component

```
export const MONTHLY_ANNUAL_LEGEND: Legend = [
  {
    title: 'Monthly',
    key: 'monthly',
    subItems: [
      {
        type: 'bar',
        key: 'progress'
      },
      {
        type: 'line',
        key: 'goal'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Annual',
    key: 'annual',
    subItems: [
      {
        type: 'line',
        key: 'progress'
      },
      {
        type: 'line',
        key: 'goal'
      },
    ],
  },
] as const;
```

And wanted to have a resulted type:

```
type LegendKeys = 'monthly_progress' | 'monthly_goal' | 'annual_progress' | 'annual_goal';
```

Which is a combination of `MONTHLY_ANNUAL_LEGEND[number]['key']` and `MONTHLY_ANNUAL_LEGEND[number]['subItems'][number]['key']`

The first thing I've found is to make a builder-function which will return you a type, applicable for union type, but didn't found a solution to type `subItems`

```
function makeLegendItem<Key extends string>(item: LegendItem<Key>): LegendItem<Key> {
  return item;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a recursive type which goes through the object would look like this:

```
type LegendKeys<T extends readonly any[]> = T extends readonly (infer I)[] 
  ? I extends Record<"key", string> & Record<"subItems", readonly any[]>
    ? `${I["key"]}_${LegendKeys<I["subItems"]>}` 
    : I extends {key: string} 
      ? I["key"] 
      : never
  : never

type Test = LegendKeys<typeof MONTHLY_ANNUAL_LEGEND>
// 'monthly_progress' | 'monthly_goal' | 'annual_progress' | 'annual_goal'
```

This has the benefit of working for any depth. So a `subItem` could also have its own `subItems` and the type would still work.

I had to specify `readonly` at multiple points since you used `as const` at the variable initialization.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=40&ssc=53&pln=32&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLIHkByAVACQBkBNAfQEEccBVCosogUQHEmcAROAXjgG0AsACg4cAN7DRomAEsYAG2AAuOAHIMKGAAt5AT1UAaSVIDWwXStUBbTTv1GRU1AFcARgEkYwK6hWDHUuLGgdK6YMpqrgCGUIbBIWYWamBQEADmUMCoqKrxogC%20DiFBASEwYRGq8jLIwHGlgYmWaRBR8rkNcIXxALpFXf0SpbIKlRTIyM5t9Y3mllETU%2039oi4eXj5%20eSXFoeGW1bUzu03JqRlZOdvdnUO7cOX7aod1Kwlzai3T1299xjc9OBRVCIFDoADcwmEj2AcCIwDSwGQABMANLmVAAHjwcFAXhRIMyUWRKD0QOQuj4PQAfDw4Di8UjkYTgMTSbo4AAKGoAM2AUDg7gAlFS4MYAPyC3EgfHMuAAJWASCgyMxACJEmqDHB0FAamlaQAyBVK6CqtVrTzeVBauBEknIMkLSk0%20KSgAGABIxO4%20BrzGqevkyN74YiUejdFjfRa3FafIHqfl3WLSip3NLZSCxKddfr8qnipKY5rAdsVLUAG784wV4DVqBQoQw%20lZeC8MNMyNYmEQHlwbD4YjkKi0eiMVjsDjUoA)

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. This is the thing I need to learn about more, because it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use template literals:

```
type Legend = typeof MONTHLY_ANNUAL_LEGEND[number];

type Items =`${Legend["key"]}_${Legend["subItems"][number]["key"]}`;
```

Comment: Yeah...I've tried something similar, but resulted type is 
``monthly_${any}` | `annual_${any}``. In the Tobias answer's resulted type is the one I looked for: `"monthly_progress" | "monthly_goal" | "annual_progress" | "annual_goal"`

Comment: `"monthly_progress" | "monthly_goal" | "annual_progress" | "annual_goal"` is the result here as well